# How to use Jsoup to get href link without the extra characters?

Tags: java, jsoup

I have an Element list of which i'm using jsoup's method attr() to get the href attribute.
Here is part of my code:

```
    String searchTerm = "tutorial+programming+"+i_SearchPhrase;
    int num = 10;
    String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?q="+searchTerm+"&num="+num;
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).userAgent("chrome/5.0").get();   
    Elements results = doc.select("h3.r > a");
    String linkHref;

    for (Element result : results) {
        linkHref = result.attr("href").replace("/url?q=","");
        //some more unrelated code...
        }
```

So for example, when i use the search prase "test", the attr("href") produces (first in the list):

linkHref = https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing/&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwi_lI-T69jTAhXIbxQKHU1kBlAQFggTMAA&usg=AFQjCNHr6EzeYegPDdpHJndLJ-889Sj3EQ

where i only want: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing/

What is the best way to fix this? Do i just add some string operations on linkHref (which i know how) or is there a way to make the href attribute contain the shorter link to begin with?
Thank you in advanced

Comment: If you know that your links will always be in the above format, you could use String's `lastIndexOf()` method to find the last forward slash, and remove all characters from that index onwards.

Comment: @patrick-hainge i'm not sure what the characters following that last slash mean or where they came from, therefore i don't know if other links will always be in the above format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always want to remove the `query` parameters you can make use of `String.indexOf()` e.g.

```
int lastPos;
if(linkHref.indexOf("?") > 0) {
   lastPos = linkHref.indexOf("?");
} else if (linkHref.indexOf("&") > 0){
   lastPos = linkHref.indexOf("&");
}
else lastPos = -1;

if(lastPos != -1)
linkHref = linkHref.subsring(0, lastPos);
```

Comment: @Atalia.d I updated my answer. You can check for the first index of any character in this case it's `&`

Comment: Since i don't know the meaning of those extra characters, can i be sure it'll always go by the same format? i.e. is it only "?" and "&" i should be worried about?

Comment: @Atalia.d These are query parameters. They will always start like that.